# Unlinking sub forms

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a database which has an enourmous amount of subforms which are located on various tabs within one main form. It seems to me that all of these linked sub forms are causing the database to be excessively slow.  I am wondering if in this type of situation it is possible to unlink the sub forms while they are not in use? Would this improve the performanance of the database?  If so, how is this done?  Below is some code on how i link the sub forms upon entering a tab but would like to know what code would unlink these forms on the 'de-activate' event.

```
Private Sub Form_Click()


    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain071.LinkMasterFields = "txtMicroProcess01f"
    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain071.LinkChildFields = "ID"

    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain14.LinkMasterFields = "txtMicroProcess01f"
    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain14.LinkChildFields = "subprocessID"

    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain10c.LinkMasterFields = "txtMicroProcess01f"
    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain10c.LinkChildFields = "ID"

    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain101.LinkMasterFields = "txtMicroProcess01f"
    Form_frmValueChain01.Form.frmValueChain101.LinkChildFields = "ID"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be more productive to outright detach the subforms from their controls when not displayed.

Assuming code is being executed from the master form and `frmValueChain10c` is the name of a subform control as well as the subform it refers to:

```
frmValueChain10c.SourceObject = ""                  ' To detach

frmValueChain10c.SourceObject = "frmValueChain10c"  ' To reattach
```

And similarly for other subforms whenever the master form's tab control changes tabs or the master form closes.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Tuggy. Is my hypothesis correct that all those links 'behind the scenes' attributing to a slowdown in the performance?

Comment: Honestly, I've never had the chance to test this, but if nothing else closing the subforms should reduce memory load a bit. You should definitely run some fairly thorough tests to see if this actually makes (enough of) a performance difference on the machines you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I am noticing that once you unlink all the underlying forms, it becomes difficult when working in design view because they are no longer displayed in detail but only as blank box/rectangles with the words 'no record source' written inside

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua: Right, you'll want to make sure to restore the `SourceObject` whenever the form closes for best results.